# Java switch error

Tags: java, switch-statement

I keep getting this error when my switch is executed. I can run through 'A' but when i try and execute 'B' it throws this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException:
>   String index out of range: 0  at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   PatientManagementSystem.main(PatientManagementSystem.java:142)

HERE IS MY CODE:

```
    boolean quit = false;
    //While loop for repeating menu
    do {
        System.out.println("\n" + "<<<Patient Management Menu>>>");
        System.out.println("A - Admit Patient");
        System.out.println("B - Record Procedure");
        System.out.println("C - Discharge Patient");
        System.out.println("D - Display ALL Patient Records");
        System.out.println("X - Exit Menu");

        String choice = sc.nextLine();
        char choiceEntry = choice.charAt(0);

        //Start switch
        switch (choiceEntry){
            case 'A':
            case 'a':
                    System.out.println("Enter the patient number of the patient to be admitted:");
                    String admitting = sc.nextLine();
                    Patient findA = null;

                    //Loop thorough the patients
                    for (int i = 0; i < patient.length; i++){

                        if (patient[i].getNumber().equals(admitting)){
                            findA = patient[i];
                        }
                    }
                    if (findA == null){
                        System.out.println("Error! - Patient record not found!");
                    }
                    else{
                        findA.admit();
                        System.out.println("Patient " + "'" + findA.getName() + "' " + "was successfully admitted.");

                    }   

                    break;
            case 'B':
            case 'b':
                    System.out.println("Enter the patient number of the patient to update records:");
                    String procedure = sc.nextLine();
                    Patient findB = null;
                    for (int i = 0; i < patient.length; i++){

                        if (patient[i].getNumber().equals(procedure)){
                        findB = patient[i];
                        }
                    }
                    if (findB == null){
                        System.out.println("Error! - Patient record not found!");
                    }
                    else{
                        System.out.println("Enter the procedure description:");
                        String description = sc.nextLine();
                        System.out.println("Enter the procedure length (in hours)");
                        int duration = sc.nextInt();
                        findB.recordProcedure(description, duration);
                        if (findB.admit() == true){
                            System.out.println("Error - Patient " + findB.getName() + " is not currently admitted!");
                        }
                        else{
                            System.out.println("Procedure details for " + findB.getName() + " has been successfully recorded");
                        }

                    }


                    break;
            case 'C':
            case 'c':
                    break;
            case 'D':
            case 'd':
                    break;
            case 'X':
            case 'x':
                    quit = true;
                    break;
            default: 
                    System.out.println("ERROR - Invalid selection entered!");
                    break;

        }

    }   while (!quit);
```

Comment: can you point out which is line does  (PatientManagementSystem.java:142) indicate

Comment: Problem seems to with accessing string index which is out of its bounds. Just debug and figure out :)

Comment: Out of bounds with index of 0 means your String is empty. E.g when you press enter without entering anything.

Comment: I ran the debugger and it indicated that the problem was on
"char choiceEntry = choice.charAt(0);"

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that a non-empty line is entered, e.g.:

```
 char choiceEntry = 'X';
 while( true ){
    System.out.println("\n" + "<<<Patient Management Menu>>>");
    System.out.println("A - Admit Patient");
    System.out.println("B - Record Procedure");
    System.out.println("C - Discharge Patient");
    System.out.println("D - Display ALL Patient Records");
    System.out.println("X - Exit Menu");

    String choice = sc.nextLine().trim();
    if( choice.length() > 0 ){
        choiceEntry = choice.charAt(0);
        break;
    }
    System.out.println( "Please enter your choice" );
}
```

Comment: Thank you, @laune, it worked! (I did however have to remove the break though for it to.
But now i'm stuck with another problem, after 'B' is successfully executed it will show another menu selection with an error for incorrect input and then the menu will appear again...
(Like this)
<<<Patient Management Menu>>>
A - Admit Patient
B - Record Procedure
C - Discharge Patient
D - Display ALL Patient Records
X - Exit Menu
ERROR - Invalid selection entered!

<<<Patient Management Menu>>>
A - Admit Patient
B - Record Procedure
C - Discharge Patient
D - Display ALL Patient Records
X - Exit Menu

Comment: It works for me - with the break which is essential. Note that the while loop I introduced is inside your do loop which should continue to work as before.